# Getting a random record where unix timestamp date is yesterday

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has the columns USERID and TIMESTAMP. The TIMESTAMP column is an UNIX timestamp value.

I want to get a random record from the table where the TIMESTAMP falls in the previous day. I want the records only that falls yesterday and not before and after.

How could I do this with MySQL?

I tried the following and does not look like working as expected. Am I doing anything silly?

```
select * from mytable 
where time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 day))
and time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 day))
```

PS: I have not included the condition of randomness in the above SQL

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "does not look like working as expected"? What are you getting? And how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: I get values that are beyond "yesterdays" date value and not exactly the timestamp that fall a day before..

Comment: That will give you values between yesterday and 2 days ago right?

Comment: I expect this to give the timestamp values that fall between yesterday and day before yesterday. Correct me if I am not making sense.

Comment: This looks like it would be based upon the time also and not just the date. `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE time < yesterday at this time AND time > two days ago at this time` which is not what you want I believe. use @Mureinik answer below to use only date part and not time.

Comment: Thanks guys. I got your point.. I had a wrong logic..

Comment: And I was all ready to lay this on you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9e52/5

Comment: Next time, I will have a fiddle posted for my questions to make your life easier :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `DATE_SUB`, you can build your condition using `DATEDIFF`, which only takes the date part into account and ignores the time part:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) = 1
```

From here, to produce a single random record is easy:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     mytable 
WHERE    DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT    1
```